# Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_FOUND)

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am working an a hello-world level program using wxWidgets in Ubuntu.

The code compiles with

```
g++ HelloWorld.cpp `wx-config --libs` `wx-config --cxxflags` -o HelloWorldApp -I../inc
```

```
maot@HP-Pavilion-dv7:~/Perforce/maot_HP_Pavilion_dv7_full_02/WxWidgets/Learning_01/src$ which wx-config
/home/maot/Perforce/wxWidgets-3.1.0/gtk-build/wx-config
maot@HP-Pavilion-dv7:~/Perforce/maot_HP_Pavilion_dv7_full_02/WxWidgets/Learning_01/src$
```

...which makes sense because I put the path to wx-config in the PATH environment variable. I compiled wxWidgets myself.

Now I want to use cmake. My CMakeLists.txt file attempt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(WxWidgets_Learning_01)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++)

message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE = ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG " -g3 ")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "")

message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE = ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")

include_directories(../inc)
include_directories(../api/IBJts/source/cppclient/client)
include_directories(../api/IBJts/source/cppclient)

# wxWidgets header files start
include_directories(/home/maot/Perforce/wxWidgets-3.1.0/include)
include_directories(/home/maot/Perforce/wxWidgets-3.1.0/gtk-build/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.1)
# wxWidgets header files end

# wxWidgets defines start
add_definitions(-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__)
# wxWidgets defines finish

# Directories with wxWidget libs start
link_directories(/home/maot/Perforce/wxWidgets-3.1.0/gtk-build/lib)
# Directories with wxWidget libs finish

SET(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR /home/maot/Perforce/wxWidgets-3.1.0/gtk-build/lib)
SET(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION mswud)

# https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindwxWidgets.html
# Note that for MinGW users the order of libs is important!
find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS net gl core base REQUIRED)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wextra -Wall -pthread -lm ")

file(GLOB sources "../src/*.cpp" )
file(GLOB headers "../inc/*.h" )

set(daytrading_sources ${sources} ${headers})

add_executable(WxWidgets_Learning_01 ${sources})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

Output:

```
maot@HP-Pavilion-dv7:~/Perforce/maot_HP_Pavilion_dv7_full_02/WxWidgets/Learning_01/src$ \rm -rf CMakeFiles/ ; cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = -g
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE = -O3 -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG =  -g3 
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE = 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:832 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:40 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/maot/Perforce/maot_HP_Pavilion_dv7_full_02/WxWidgets/Learning_01/src/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
maot@HP-Pavilion-dv7:~/Perforce/maot_HP_Pavilion_dv7_full_02/WxWidgets/Learning_01/src$
```

I think find_package can not find wxWidgets and I do not understand why. I am uncertain about this mswud thing because I can not find explanations about it; ms sounds like Bill G. I have tried a few values for wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR but no luck. Any help is welcome: What value should wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR have, and is mswud any good?

=== Edit below ===

I followed https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_and_getting_started, using the --prefix=$(pwd) option. make install is not needed, it sais.

How to put the results of wx-config in CMakeLists.txt?

```
maot@HP-Pavilion-dv7:~$ wx-config --cxxflags
-I/home/maot/Perforce/wxWidgets-3.1.0/gtk-build/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.1 -I/home/maot/Perforce/wxWidgets-3.1.0/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread
maot@HP-Pavilion-dv7:~$ 
maot@HP-Pavilion-dv7:~$ wx-config --libs
-L/home/maot/Perforce/wxWidgets-3.1.0/gtk-build/lib -pthread   -Wl,-rpath,/home/maot/Perforce/wxWidgets-3.1.0/gtk-build/lib -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.1 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.1 -lwx_baseu_net-3.1 -lwx_baseu-3.1 
maot@HP-Pavilion-dv7:~$
```

I got my code compiling and running using the CMakeLists.txt file below; I realise it is not the way things are intended.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(WxWidgets_Learning_01)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++)

message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE = ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG " -g3 ")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "")

message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE = ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")

include_directories(../inc)
include_directories(../api/IBJts/source/cppclient/client)
include_directories(../api/IBJts/source/cppclient)

# wxWidgets header files start
include_directories(../../../../wxWidgets-3.1.0/include)
include_directories(../../../../wxWidgets-3.1.0/gtk-build/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.1)
# wxWidgets header files end

# wxWidgets defines start
add_definitions(-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__)
# wxWidgets defines finish

# Directories with wxWidget libs start
link_directories(../../../../wxWidgets-3.1.0/gtk-build/lib)
# Directories with wxWidget libs finish

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wextra -Wall -pthread -lm ")

file(GLOB sources "../src/*.cpp" )
file(GLOB headers "../inc/*.h" )

set(daytrading_sources ${sources} ${headers})

add_executable(WxWidgets_Learning_01 ${sources})
target_link_libraries(WxWidgets_Learning_01
                      libwx_baseu-3.1.so
                      libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.1.so
                      libwx_gtk2u_gl-3.1.so
                      libwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1.so
                      libwx_gtk2u_stc-3.1.so
                      libwx_baseu_net-3.1.so
                      libwx_gtk2u_aui-3.1.so
                      libwx_gtk2u_html-3.1.so
                      libwx_gtk2u_ribbon-3.1.so
                      libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1.so
                      libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.so
                      libwx_gtk2u_core-3.1.so
                      libwx_gtk2u_propgrid-3.1.so
                      libwx_gtk2u_richtext-3.1.so
                      )
# I have just added all .so files that I found after the build.
```

Comment: You need to use `wx-config`, in the same way as you'd use `pkg-config`, in your cmakefile under Unix, don't hard code any directories. `mswud` is indeed completely wrong, this is Unicode Debug build directory under MSW and will never be used under Unix.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compile just a simple example for the prototype then thats it.

However, if you need to compile some big project - you can try to set up Anjuta/CodeBlocks/CodeLite to help. It will benefit you in the long run (especially CodeBlocks).

In terms of your questions: mswud is not good, since it (as name suggested) for Windows.

Also, for the include/lib directory you should use wx-config appropriate command, just as you used for command-line compiling.

You can also try to take a look at CMake effort by TobiasT in trac.wxwidgets.org.

Comment: I will be using CodeBlocks, but I need CMake because I may change IDEs later. I suspected that msxxx is wrong - what should it be?

Comment: @TradingDerivatives.eu, try gtk. But you shouldn't be using it anyway. Just use `wx-config --cxxflags` and `wx-config --libs` for the options. Also, did you run `make install` after compiling?